# RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure

Tags: jmeter, handshake

Im using Jmeter2.9 for testing secured webservice.
i've created a keystore and truststore for the client and the root certificates and they seem to be fine.
however, when I start using the test script I get the following error message:

```
...
AWT-EventQueue-0, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
AWT-EventQueue-0, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
AWT-EventQueue-0, called closeSocket()
AWT-EventQueue-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

i tried to modify the parameters in user.properties, jmeter.properties and system.properties for jmeter, but it didnt help.

have you any hint or tips what causes the issue and how it could be solved?

thank you.